# Zip append code after .zip extensio

Tags: php

I wanna pack a folder and download this. The packed file was created but theres a code appended after the file name so when I call the file to download it does'nt exists because "physically" they have another name. Follow the code:

```
function zip($source, $destination){
    if (!extension_loaded('zip') || !file_exists($source)) {
        return false;
    }

    $zip = new ZipArchive();
    if (!$zip->open($destination, ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE)) {
        return false;
    }

    $source = str_replace('\\', '/', realpath($source));

    if (is_dir($source) === true)
    {
        $files = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($source), RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);

        foreach ($files as $file)
        {
            $file = str_replace('\\', '/', $file);

            // Ignore "." and ".." folders
            if( in_array(substr($file, strrpos($file, '/')+1), array('.', '..')) )
                continue;

            if (is_dir($file) === true)
            {
                $zip->addEmptyDir(str_replace($source . '/', '', $file));
            }
            else if (is_file($file) === true)
            {

                $str1 = str_replace($source . '/', '', '/'.$file);
                $zip->addFromString($str1, file_get_contents($file));

            }
        }
    }
    else if (is_file($source) === true)
    {
        $zip->addFromString(basename($source), file_get_contents($source));
    }

    $zip->close();

    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
    header('Content-Type: application/force-download');
    header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="'.$file_name.'"');
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($destination));
    header('Connection: close');
    readfile($destination);
    exit();

}
```

`readfile($file_name)` is calling `filename.zip` but physically the name is `filename.zip.06452` soh I get an error.

Comment: so what is the problem?

Comment: The solution seems to be to figure out the added code and link to the proper file?

Comment: I'm calling filename.zip but physically the name is filename.zip.06452 soh I get an error.

Comment: does this code help? http://php.net/manual/de/class.ziparchive.php#110719

Comment: figure out the code is a workaround, the good will be the ziplib dont generate this code

Answer (score 0):

You should:

```
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($destination));
```

and

```
readfile($destination);
```

because that's where you wrote the archive:

```
if (!$zip->open($destination, ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE)) {
...
```

Comment: What is the issue, then?

Comment: I'm calling filename.zip but physically the name is filename.zip.06452 soh I get an error.

Comment: The question is, why they are generating the file with this code after .zip

Comment: I cannot follow you. Who is generating the file? The code you posted is a function, you call it with whatever parameters you want. It works (apart from the `Content-Disposition` header that uses the undefined variable `$file_name`). It packs some files and generates an archive stored at `$destination` then sends the archive to the browser for download. What is the problem?

Comment: The script that I posted is generating

Answer (score 0):

I got solution! This file with code at the end `myfile.zip.das87` is a temp file that the php creates when start the pack process and when is done they rename it to `myfile.zip`. I printed the error message and got `Renaming temporary file failed`, so the problem is about folder permission.
Thanks for all the tried to help.